# Wind turbine power characteristic

Tags: matlab, power-engineering, windturbine

The following graph was obtained using the MATLAB Doubly-Fed Induction Generator (DFIG) wind turbine model.

I'm confused about why spikes occur at the points A to B and C to D.

If you have any reference books related to the graph please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The system is controlled to follow this so-called "ABCD" curve, it is the [Maximum Power Point Tracking (MPPT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_point_tracking) curve for the [Doubly-Fed Induction Generator (DFIG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly-fed_electric_machine#Double-fed_induction_generator).

To get started, read the paragraphs about "ABCD" in the following:

- Xinshou Tian, Weisheng Wang, Yongning Chi, Yan Li, Chao Liu, "Virtual inertia optimisation control of DFIG and assessment of equivalent inertia time constant of power grid", *Selected Papers from the 6th IET Renewable Power Generation Conference (RPG 2017)*, [online](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1049/iet-rpg.2018.5063)
- Moulay Tahar Lamchich, Nora Lachguer, "Matlab Simulink as Simulation Tool for Wind Generation Systems Based on Doubly Fed Induction Machines", in *MATLAB: A Fundamental Tool for Scientific Computing and Engineering Applications - Volume 2*, ed Vasilios Katsikis, 2012. [online](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/11d7/c66d7e81726f2ef2198b85488d9ec595938f.pdf).

Comment: It would be useful to spell out acronyms that are not widely used.

Comment: @Barry, thanks for your comment, edited.